# Как менять color в зависимости от цвета фона?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Меню идет position: fixed, и при прокрутке меняется цвет, как менять color в зависимости от фона?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/methods-contrasting-text-backgrounds/

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/reverse-text-color-mix-blend-mode/

Answer (score 2):

Используйте css-свойство `mix-blend-mode` со значением `difference`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(
    45deg,
    #000,
    #fff 20px
  );
  padding: 50px;
}

.wrapper span {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: white;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <span>Brain Storm</span>
</div>
```